# Dynamic passing of php array to javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I try to pass my array in my php code javscript . I want to get the result of my foreach . The problem is that I only get the last array. How to get each arrays in the console.log() ?
PHP CODE :

```
function users_nb_match($value){
  $tab_nb_match_par_user = array();
  $mois_choisi = "";
  $match_ou_catego = "matching";//"categorisation";
  if(strlen($mois_choisi)==0){
      $res = sql_dico("SELECT MAX(mois) AS zemois FROM stats_".$match_ou_catego."_univers WHERE LENGTH(mois)=7");//mois de janvier
      if($res && $rez = mysql_fetch_object($res))
          $mois_choisi = $rez->zemois;
  }
  //echo formate_pieChart("Column",$tab_values,$_GET['univers']);
  $zedate = "";
  $res = sql_dico("SELECT mois, login, nb_match FROM   stats_".$match_ou_catego."_univers 
  WHERE login != '' ".((strlen($value)>0)?"
  AND univers = '".$value."'":"")." ".((strlen($mois_choisi)>0)?"
  AND mois IN ('".$mois_choisi."')":"")."
  AND LENGTH(mois)=7 ORDER BY nb_match DESC");

  //tab_value_user c'est le nb matching par utilisateurs
  while($res && $rez = mysql_fetch_object($res)){
      if(isset($tab_nb_match_par_user[$rez->login]))
          $tab_nb_match_par_user[$rez->login] += $rez->nb_match;
      else
          $tab_nb_match_par_user[$rez->login] = $rez->nb_match;
      $zedate = $rez->mois;
  }
  arsort($tab_nb_match_par_user);   
  return $tab_nb_match_par_user;}

  foreach($tab_bases as $key => $values){
      $tab_nb_match_par_user = users_nb_match($values);
  }
```

Javascript (on the same page)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var tab_nb_match_par_user = <?php   print_r(json_encode($tab_nb_match_par_user)); ?>;
  console.log(tab_nb_match_par_user);</script>
```

$tab_base contains database_name, so for each database name there are one query, and with this query I build an array

EDIT POST :
on this platform  when I select  " Tous les univers " I get only the last array . I do not dynamically retrieves my others javascript array .
I generate my graph like this :

```
function formate_pieChart(){
 $PieChart = "<div id='chart1' style='width:400px;height:400px'></div>";
 return  $PieChart;}

   function formate_barChart(){
  $BarChart = "<div id='chart2' style= 'width:60%;height:400px'></div>";
  return $BarChart;}

function formate_imageChart(){
$imgMi = "<div id='chart3' style='width:100%;height:200px;margin-right:10%'></div>";
return $imgMi;}


function genere_code($choix){
switch($choix){
    case 0:{
        return formate_barChart();
        break;
    }
    case 1:{
        return formate_pieChart();
        break;
    }
    case 2:{
        return formate_imageChart();
        break;
    }
    default:{
        return formate_barChart();
        break;
    }
  }}
if($univers=="tous") {//la variable $bdd est fixe à cet endroit
  echo genere_code(1);
}
foreach($tab_bases as $key => $values){
    $tab_nb_match_par_user = users_nb_match($values);
    $tab_mois_nb_match = mois_nb_match($values);
    echo genere_code(1);

}
```

If I click on ec_be or  ect the charts loading but if I click on "tous les univers" only the last chart is running...
note : the value of the  is "tous" for "tous les univers"

Comment: What does the `console` says?

Comment: the console gives me one array

Comment: why dont you just use json_encode?

Comment: If you have the solution I will past a great night :)

Answer (score 2):

> I want to get the result of my foreach . The problem is that I only
>   get the last array. How to get every arrays in the console.log() ?

Change

```
foreach($tab_bases as $key => $values)
{
      $tab_nb_match_par_user = users_nb_match($values);
}
```

to

```
foreach($tab_bases as $key => $values)
{
      $tab_nb_match_par_user[] = users_nb_match($values);
}
```